# How can I keep spaces after words connected to the word when text wraps?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a typing app where i need to keep the spaces at the end of the lines when there is a line break. Basically the user needs to type in the text what is shown to them. I have a fix width container where I generate the text so I have to break the lines to stay in the container. That's why I have to keep the spaces at the end of the line to let the user know what to type in next. *(The to be entered letter is highlighted)*

Here is my problem:

```html
<div style="width: 26px">
  <div style="outline: 1px solid red; white-space: pre-wrap">
    a aaaa<span style="outline: 1px solid green"> </span>a a<span 
    style="outline: 1px solid green"> </span>a
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems a bit like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). You might explain what you're actually trying to accomplish so we can present suitable solutions.

Comment: I want to keep the spaces at the end of the lines when there is a line break. Sorry if I wasn’t clear, I was forced to explain what I’ve tried.

Comment: You were clear _what_, but not _why_. What's the reason for this? Why doesn't simple padding on the container serve your needs?

Comment: I agree with @isherwood. Please review your post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, edited my post. I hope now everything is clear and someone can come up with a simple solution.